# Counting frequency of char using switches

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, increment, ref

I am trying to count the amount of time each char appears in a string, I'm using switches and a for loop, however, they are not being incremented properly. Here is my code

```
let countChar x = 
  match x with
    'A' -> countA := !countA + 1;
  | 'C' -> countC := !countC + 1;
  | 'T' -> countT := !countT + 1;
  | 'G' -> countG := !countG + 1;   
;;

let demoStri = "ACGTACGT" in 
for j = 0 to 7 do
  countChar demoStri.[j];
  let tempA = !countA in
  print_int tempA;
  print_string "\n";
  let tempC = !countC in
  print_int tempC;
  print_string "\n";
  let tempG = !countG in
  print_int tempG;
  print_string "\n";
  let tempT = !countT in 
  print_int tempT;
  print_string "\n";
done
```

But for some reason it's only incrementing 1, and it returns 1 0 0 0, 2 0 0 0, 3 0 0 0 and so on..... I was wondering if something went wrong in the process?

Comment: Why are you not using `j`?

Comment: why not List.iter ???

Comment: that was a typo, i was using something other than j in my code but changed it for this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no problem with this code in its current form, it works for me. You don't show your initializations of `countA`, `countC`, `countT`, and `countG`, but if I initialize as follows:

```
let countA = ref 0
let countC = ref 0
let countT = ref 0
let countG = ref 0
```

Then run your code I get this series of numbers (collapsed four to a line to save space):

```
1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1
2 2 1 1
2 2 2 1
2 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem here is that you are using the `tempH` variable to index the string instead of the `j` you should have been using.

```
let () = 
    let demoStri = "ACGTACGT" in 
    let countA = ref 0 in
    let countC = ref 0 in
    let countT = ref 0 in
    let countG = ref 0 in
    for j = 0 to String.length demoStri - 1 do
        match demoStri.[j] with
        | 'A'-> countA := !countA +1
        | 'C'-> countC := !countC +1
        | 'T'-> countT := !countT +1
        | 'G'-> countG := !countG +1
        | _ -> assert false
    done;
    print_int !countA; print_string "\n";
    print_int !countC; print_string "\n";
    print_int !countT; print_string "\n";
    print_int !countG; print_string "\n"
```

Comment: The problem is not with the for loop but rather it's with the function. its looping perfectly fine in my source code. Just not incrementing properly.

Comment: I did some testing and it is indeed something wrong with the code, it is only incrementing the first case, if i changed the 'A' -> countA := !countA + 1 with 'C' -> countC := !countC +1 it will increment countC instead rather than countA.

Comment: my apologies, you were right, I was simply overthinking things thank you

Answer (score 0):

An addendum to existing answers, imperative features and mutable state are wholly unnecessary to solve this. You can fold over the string, updating a record on each iteration. The result will be a tally of each character.

```
# type count = {a: int; c: int; t: int; g: int};;
type count = { a : int; c : int; t : int; g : int; }
# let print_int_endline = Format.printf "%d\n";;
val print_int_endline : int -> unit = <fun>
# let {a; c; t; g} =
    String.fold_left
      (fun ({a;c;t;g} as r) ->
         function
         | 'A' -> {r with a=a+1}
         | 'C' -> {r with c=c+1}
         | 'T' -> {r with t=t+1}
         | 'G' -> {r with g=g+1}
         |  _  -> r)
      {a=0; c=0; t=0; g=0}
      "ACGTACGT"
  in
  print_int_endline a;
  print_int_endline c;
  print_int_endline t;
  print_int_endline g;;
2
2
2
2
- : unit = ()
```